# Can't seem to prevent my js calculator to put more than two decimals

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, calculator

First things first here is the code pen of the project;
https://codepen.io/furkancodes-the-typescripter/pen/jOyGJvx

I have tried searching for "." through contains() also with a condition to make it disabled but it does not work as I want it to.

```
decimal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  decimal = e.target.value;
  if (display.innerHTML === '') {
    result = display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('0.');
  } else if (display.innerHTML === output && display.innerHTML.indexOf(".") < 0) {
    display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.concat('.');
  }
});
```

Also tried to come up with a solution like above but I am sure I am failing to grasp something here.  Can anyone let me know what is wrong and lead me to the correct path to "prevent my calculator allowing more than one decimal" and any other improvements I can make.

Sample input:

4...4

Expected output:

4.4 ( not more than one decimal into the calculator display)

Comment: please add a sample input and the expected output to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I did not get what you mean to be honest, but I tried my best explaining my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stop the user from entering more than one decimal point for a single input, you can implement a counter.

`let decimalCount = 0;`

For the `click` handler for `.number` buttons add the following check.

```
// For  the decimal increment decimal counter
    if (number.id === ".") {
      decimalCount++;
    }

    // For more than one decimal don't do anything. Return
    if (number.id === "." && decimalCount > 1) {
      return;
    }
```

When the user enters another input (`.operator` `click` handler) reset the decimal counter to `decimalCount = 0;`.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/calculator-no-multiple-decimals-2fjnm

Comment: How could I miss such an obvious approach. I learned a new perspective today. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

The write method to use for string is `includes`.

Using it solves the problem

```
decimal.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(display.innerHTML.includes('.') || firstNumber.innerHTML.includes('.')){
    decimal.disabled = true;
  } else {
    decimal.disabled = false;
  }

})
```

Comment: I have been using the wrong method all the time then.

Comment: @Metalwell The contains() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether a node is a descendant of a specified node, it's not meant for substring check.